# Data don't display when I use controller - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following example,where I am using a controller. And inside that controller,there is a json object holding some values. However,those values are not displayed in the screen.

```js
<script>
        var app = module.module('myTemplate',[]);
        app.controller('alcazarController',function(){
             var alcazarPark=
                         {
                           title:'Alcazar Park',
                           image: 'http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/alcazar.png',
                           description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
                           
                        };
            this.alcazarPark = alcazarPark;
        });
</script>
```

```css
body{
    background: url("http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/wallpaper6.png") no-repeat;
    height: 500px;

    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   
    
}
.row-content-1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,100,200,0.8) !important;
    color: #fff;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="myTemplate">
    <!-- Alcazar Park row-->   
    <div class="row row-content-1" ng-controller="alcazarController">
        <div id="alcazarModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
       
    
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 center-block" id="alcazar-row">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                
                    <img ng-src={{alcazarPark.image}} class="media-object img-thumbnail" id="alcazar-image" alt="alcazar">
                
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="media-heading">{{alcazarPark.title}}</h3>
                <p style="font-size:20px;">{{alcazarPark.description}}</p>
                <p style="text-align:left"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alcazarModal"> More&raquo;</a></p>   
            </div>
              
            </div>
```

Somehow the json object variables are not visible,so {{alcazarPark.title}} etc are null. Any ideas? Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

`var app = module.module('myTemplate',[]);`

to this

`var app = angular.module('myTemplate',[]);`

**EDITED**

also use `controller as ctrl` in your view

`<div class="row row-content-1" ng-controller="alcazarController as ctrl">`

```
<div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">{{ctrl.alcazarPark.title}}</h3>
    <p style="font-size:20px;">{{ctrl.alcazarPark.description}}</p>
    <p style="text-align:left"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alcazarModal"> More&raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kjFHbt1L5WT52KQIjMhN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However,I still have the same problem:(

Comment: That's much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to inject `$scope` in your controller, and then assign value to `$scope`

Try this

```
<script>
        var app = module.module('myTemplate',[]);
        app.controller('alcazarController',function($scope){
             var alcazarPark=
                         {
                           title:'Alcazar Park',
                           image: 'http://www.theo-android.co.uk/github-images/alcazar.png',
                           description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'

                        };
            $scope.alcazarPark = alcazarPark;
        });
</script>
```

Comment: the first answer is more better with the ControllerAs-Syntax!